# Where are comment flags reviewed?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

They don't seem to meet the description of any of the review queue names/descriptions:

- Close votes: "Vote whether or not to close **questions** with close votes."
- Reopen votes: "Vote whether or not to reopen closed **questions**."
- Low quality answers: "Identify, then improve or delete low quality **answers**."
- Suggested edits: "Approve, reject, or improve **edits** suggested by users."
- First answers: "Help new users be successful on the site by reviewing their first **answers**."
- First questions: "Help new users be successful on the site by reviewing their first **questions**."
- Late answers: "Review new **answers** on old questions. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam."
- Triage: "Help identify the quality of **questions**."

Is it a diamond-moderator-only queue? Or something that I just can't see?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A small percentage of comments are deleted entirely by the community, either with a [single flag when the comment contains certain phrases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/323179) or by having enough flags cast on the comment. There's no way for regular users to know about comment flags other than the ones they've cast themselves.

Pending comment flags are fed into the moderator flag queue for [diamond moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) to handle. Staff with moderator privileges can also see this queue, but they don't usually handle flags. For moderators, the number of posts in the flag queue (i.e. the number of posts with at least one post or comment flag) is shown on the top bar in blue. The queue itself can be filtered by type of flag (e.g. only showing "No longer needed" flags). Any flags on the question or the question's answers are also shown when a moderator visits the question page directly. However, the flag queue isn't listed on the [All Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page, or in the dropdown that shows the queues available to regular users.

(For what it's worth, I'm a moderator on other Stack Exchange sites, which is why I know all the trivial minutiae.)

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, that is a diamond-mod only system (I would very much hesitate to call it a "queue" in the traditional "queue" sense).

Normal users don't review it or participate in the process beyond flags since users can't see deleted comments, or escalate to appropriate folks in a timely fashion in the event that a comment sends something *wholly* inappropriate.

Comment: It's a queue in the sense that the flags are waiting their turn :D

Comment: @Makoto what makes you hesitate to call it a queue, other than the fact that it's just for diamond moderators?

Comment: @Samathingamajig: That's the only reason. Queues in the more modern Stack Overflow are often community efforts and not just limited to diamond mods.